# Difference b/w Discriminator Value And Discriminator Column in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

What is difference b/w Discriminator Value And Discriminator Column?
Purpose of both term and when to use? 
Note: I have read many topics after searching but totally confused. Please Explain with the scenario. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A single table can contain entities of different types.

If a table contains entities of different types then each row must identify the entity type it contains.

The "Discriminator Column" is the column in the table that stores this identification information.

The "Discriminator Value" is the specific value stored in the "Discriminator Column" of a row identifying the entity type.

Answer (score 0):

You can either define the column name with a @DiscriminatorColumn annotation on the superclass or Hibernate will use DTYPE as its default name.

The @DiscriminatorValue annotation is optional if you use Hibernate. If you don’t provide a discriminator value, Hibernate will use the simple entity name by default.